# Как реализовать меняющийся фон?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать меняющийся фон без перезагрузки страницы по таймеру на JS?

Comment: @Тимофей Садовых, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Привели бы пример страницы, для который вы будете менять фон. В зависимости от того, что является фоном - текст или картинка, код будет немного разный.

Вот вам [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/5heuf7bh/2/). 3 варианта фона являются элементами массива. Через интервал в одну секунду 1 из элементов подставляется в стиль страницы.

Answer (score 1):

[Например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)

Comment: @nekaneka, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.